# Using pandas to_datetime with timestamps

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I'm trying to covert my these timestamps into a `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M` format. Here's a sample of the data:

```
0    1450753200
1    1450756800
2    1450760400
3    1450764000
4    1450767600
Name: ohlcv_start_date, dtype: int64
```

Could someone explain what type of timestamp these are and what code I need to convert them properly, because when I use:

```
pd.to_datetime(df[TS], unit='ms').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

It converts the time into:

```
0        1970-01-01 00:00
1        1970-01-01 00:00
2        1970-01-01 00:00
3        1970-01-01 00:00
4        1970-01-01 00:00
```

Which isn't correct

EDIT: Thanks Mr Chum.

What i'm actually trying to do is merge the values of different assets by timestamp. Each asset starts and finishes at slightly different times and Upon analysis it seems there is gaps in the data:

```
 market_trading_pair  next_future_timestep_return ohlcv_start_date  \
0        Poloniex_ETH_BTC                 3.013303e-03    2015-12-22 03      
1        Poloniex_ETH_BTC                 3.171481e-03    2015-12-22 05   
2        Poloniex_ETH_BTC                -1.381575e-03    2015-12-22 07   
3        Poloniex_ETH_BTC                -4.327704e-03    2015-12-22 08
```

The best I can think to solve this problem is to create a new data frame and fill in the rows with time stamps incrementing by one hours, from here i can simple merge in the asset data. Any idea how to generate ascending timstamps ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pass `unit='s'` to get the values as it's [epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):

```
In [106]:
pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='s')
Out[106]:
index
0   2015-12-22 03:00:00
1   2015-12-22 04:00:00
2   2015-12-22 05:00:00
3   2015-12-22 06:00:00
4   2015-12-22 07:00:00
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

You can convert to string if you desire:

```
In [107]:

pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='s').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
Out[107]:
index
0    2015-12-22 03:00
1    2015-12-22 04:00
2    2015-12-22 05:00
3    2015-12-22 06:00
4    2015-12-22 07:00
Name: timestamp, dtype: object
```

Comment: EdChum does it once again!

Comment: @EdChum For bonus points, how would we fill in a blank dataframe column with dates ,incrementing by one hour and starting from t1 ending at t2.

Comment: If you have a new question then you should post a new question, besides this should work: `pd.date_range(start=t1, end=t2, freq='H')`

Comment: Wow, beautifully simple, i tried to search for something like this but i kept getting 'how to convert timstamp' posts. Can you suggest a method to look for functions like this ? or do you just need to know pandas well

Comment: dunno, the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html) are pretty comprehensive

Comment: Thanks! sometimes it is `'ms'` millisecond, depending on your data.